# Liquid - rails - render_component issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, liquid-layout

In my next rails project I want to use liquid pages (so that my graphic designer can do his stuff without bothering be :D) By my question is

will i be able to use

render_component and render :partial commands inside my liquid layout. If possible how

thanks in advance

cheers,
sameera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liquid provides an [include tag](http://liquid.rubyforge.org/) you can use inside a template to include external templates. However, it isn't equiparable to the render component or partial feature in Rails.

Also, render component has been deprecated times ago. You shouldn't use it.